# How to get extra Nvidia GPU info in Windows?

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card, gpu

So the Nvidia driver for Linux gives you some nice information such as:

- VBIOS version
- GPU Utilization
- Video Engine Utilization
- PCIe bandwidth utilization

The Nvidia control panel for Windows doesn't list this information. **How can access this information from Windows?**

Here's a screenshot from Ubuntu:

[image]

Comment: I can find the VBIOS Version in Windows, but I'm looking for the rest of the stuff still.  I know there are 3rd party monitoring software like MSI Afterburner that will display the rest of this information (or most of it).

Comment: have you tried ProcessHacker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much searching, I figured out that [OpenHardwareMonitor](https://openhardwaremonitor.org/) has the ability to read `GPU Core` load, `GPU Memory Controller` load and `GPU Video Engine` load out-of-the-box:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can see all the information by going to the System Information in Windows. On that window there is  **Components expandable menu** in the left and expand it and select the component you want to see (on your question it should be the display). You will see all the necessary information of your hardware components from there.

To open the system information panel, do the following:

- Right click the start menu and click "run"
- Type "msinfo32" in the box then press "Enter"

Comment: I've already looked there. It does not display the information I am after.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [compile the plugin **NvGpuPlugin**](https://github.com/processhacker2/plugins-extra/tree/master/NvGpuPlugin) for [ProcessHacker](https://wj32.org/processhacker/downloads.php) to see additional nVIDIA specific details.

The GPU Utilization + memory usage is shown for all GPUs in the GPU tab of Systeminformation Window in ProcessHacker:

[image]